# PostgreSQL migration from id(bigint) to id(uuid) while preserving relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have many tables and a lot of data and I would like to change all primary key types from `bigint` to `uuid` type. I have no idea how to preserve relations. Here is an example.

This means I am planning to

- Add new column uuid of type uuid
- Rename id column to id_obsolete
- Rename uuid to id

Now I somehow need to preserve relations, so for example, if I have a table
`users` that has `person_id (bigint)` column, this should get migrated to `person_id (uuid)` and maintain the relationship. How can I do this without losing any data?

Comment: Lets use a an example here thats easier to reason with. Lets say you have *users* and *pets* and *pets* reference `users.id` with `pets.user_id`. If you want to change the primary key of *users* to a UUID you would create a `pets.user_uuid` column before you rename/delete anything.

Comment: This column would be filled with something like `UPDATE pets SET pets.user_uuid = users.uuid FROM pets LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = pets.uiid`. Once you have taken care of this you can delete `pets.user_id` and rename this column. Note that you may need to remove the foreign key constraints.

Comment: Once you have done this for every reference you can delete and rename the column on users. Then you need to re-add the foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's create sample data:

```
create table employees 
(
    id int4, 
    emp_name varchar, 
    emp_surname varchar
);

insert into employees (id, emp_name, emp_surname) values (100, 'Tim', 'James');
insert into employees (id, emp_name, emp_surname) values (101, 'Bella', 'Tucker');
insert into employees (id, emp_name, emp_surname) values (102, 'Ryan', 'Metcalfe');
insert into employees (id, emp_name, emp_surname) values (103, 'Dominic', 'King');

create table transactions 
(
    id int4, 
    emp_id int4, 
    tran_date date, 
    total int4
);

insert into transactions (id, emp_id, tran_date, total) values (1, 100, now(), 120); 
insert into transactions (id, emp_id, tran_date, total) values (2, 100, now(), 195);
insert into transactions (id, emp_id, tran_date, total) values (3, 100, now(), 250);
insert into transactions (id, emp_id, tran_date, total) values (4, 100, now(), 50);
insert into transactions (id, emp_id, tran_date, total) values (5, 101, now(), 70); 
insert into transactions (id, emp_id, tran_date, total) values (6, 101, now(), 125);
insert into transactions (id, emp_id, tran_date, total) values (7, 102, now(), 600);
insert into transactions (id, emp_id, tran_date, total) values (8, 102, now(), 15);
insert into transactions (id, emp_id, tran_date, total) values (9, 102, now(), 90);
insert into transactions (id, emp_id, tran_date, total) values (10, 103, now(), 10);
insert into transactions (id, emp_id, tran_date, total) values (11, 103, now(), 60);
insert into transactions (id, emp_id, tran_date, total) values (12, 103, now(), 155);
insert into transactions (id, emp_id, tran_date, total) values (13, 103, now(), 30);

create table item_sales 
(
    id int4, 
    emp_id int4, 
    process_date date, 
    price int4
);

insert into item_sales (id, emp_id, process_date, price) values (1, 100, now(), 5); 
insert into item_sales (id, emp_id, process_date, price) values (2, 101, now(), 7);
insert into item_sales (id, emp_id, process_date, price) values (3, 102, now(), 12);
insert into item_sales (id, emp_id, process_date, price) values (4, 101, now(), 5);
insert into item_sales (id, emp_id, process_date, price) values (5, 103, now(), 9); 
insert into item_sales (id, emp_id, process_date, price) values (6, 102, now(), 12);
insert into item_sales (id, emp_id, process_date, price) values (7, 100, now(), 9);
insert into item_sales (id, emp_id, process_date, price) values (8, 101, now(), 5);
insert into item_sales (id, emp_id, process_date, price) values (9, 100, now(), 9);
insert into item_sales (id, emp_id, process_date, price) values (10, 103, now(), 1);
insert into item_sales (id, emp_id, process_date, price) values (11, 102, now(), 6);
```

We need convert id field on employees to uuid and update all `emp_id` on another tables. First, create new `uuid` field.

```
ALTER TABLE employees 
ADD id_new uuid;

ALTER TABLE item_sales 
ADD emp_id_new uuid;

ALTER TABLE transactions 
ADD emp_id_new uuid;
```

Update our new uuid field using generate uuid function:

```
update employees
set id_new = uuid_generate_v4();
```

Then update another tables using join:

```
update item_sales sls  
set emp_id_new = emp.id_new
from employees emp 
where emp.id = sls.emp_id;

update transactions trn  
set emp_id_new = emp.id_new
from employees emp 
where emp.id = trn.emp_id;
```

After then we can delete old id and emp_id fields and rename new fields to old name.

```
ALTER TABLE employees 
DROP COLUMN id;

ALTER TABLE item_sales 
DROP COLUMN emp_id;

ALTER TABLE transactions 
DROP COLUMN emp_id;

ALTER TABLE employees 
RENAME COLUMN id_new TO id;

ALTER TABLE item_sales 
RENAME COLUMN emp_id_new TO emp_id;

ALTER TABLE transactions 
RENAME COLUMN emp_id_new TO emp_id;
```